# App using Firebase works on phone, but doesn't work in Genymotion

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am building an android app using android studio, and using Firebase as a back-end system. I was trying for hours to find the reason why firebase wasn't working on the emulator of genymotion, however then after I uploaded the app to my personal phone, it worked perfectly. 
Any idea why firebase doesn't work sometimes on the emulator while it works on an actual device?

Answer (score 0):

It might be due the emulator that doesn't have internet access, it's weird that it's not working since I have used Genymotion free version and it was working fine.

Did you added your Internet permissions in your manifest ?

Make sure you have this in your manifest

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```